# Dynamic select freeze on adding options in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a `<select>` that I added with JQ ,
its loadded all options from a class (value + data) list return by `$.ajax` call, and load it to a div.

My code:

```
varTempDiv+= '<select class="selectFromList" width="200">';
$.each(data.d, function (index) {                                          
    varTempDiv+= '<option value="' + this.value >+ '">' + this.txtName + '</option>';
});
varTempDiv+= '</select>';
$("#loadedDiv").html(varTempDiv);
```

It work fine at all in chrome , 
but in ie8 its froze to some second append to list length.
The length start with 100 to 1000+ items.

How can i fix that things?
Thanks!!

Comment: You have a dropdownlist with 1000+ items? That might cause a problem for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using native `for` loop instead of `jQuery.each`. It should give you significant performance improvement especially if you have so many items in your array. Take a look at this comparison http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/69.

Comment: Its much faster!
its stil freezing but its now acceptable .
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change

```
varTempDiv+= '<option value="' + this.value >+ '">' + this.txtName + '</option>';
```

to

```
varTempDiv+= '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.txtName + '</option>';
```

Thousand items in a select also seems unusable, maybe you should consider a different design.